# Prove that $X \subset Y \implies f^{-1}(X) \subset f^{-1}(Y)$

Tags: functions, proof-writing, inverse

Let E and F be two sets and $f: E \to F $ be a function, and $X, Y \subset F$.

Prove that $X \subset Y \implies f^{-1}(X) \subset f^{-1}(Y)$

My answer:

Let $y \in X$, then $f^{-1}(y) \in f^{-1}(X)$.

Since $X \subset Y$, then $y \in Y$.

If $y \in Y$, then $f^{-1}(y) \in f^{-1}(Y)$.

So, $f^{-1}(y) \in f^{-1}(X)$ and $f^{-1}(y) \in f^{-1}(Y)$, then $f^{-1}(X) \subset f^{-1}(Y)$.

Is this proof ok?

Comment: You might have that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ may be empty. I would start with suppose that $a \in f^{-1}(X)$ and unwrap the definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof looks pretty good! There are some things that I can say though.

For starters, we want to show the implication $x\in f^{-1}(X)\implies x\in f^{-1}(Y)$. Because of this, we don't really need to look for $y\in Y$. You made this claim, and then the corresponding claims about the preimages with a subtle implication to if $y\in f^{-1}(X)\cap f^{-1}(Y)$ then $f^{-1}(X)\subset f^{-1}(Y)$. But this actually doesn't follow. See if you can revamp it.

If you'd like, I've rewritten it below but, I would only look at this after trying again first.

Suppose $X\subset Y$ (both subsets of the codomain, $F$), and take an element $x\in f^{-1}(X)$. Then $f(x)\in X$ by the definition of preimage. Since $X\subset Y$, we have $f(x)\in Y$. Therefore, if $x\in f^{-1}(X)$ then $x\in f^{-1}(Y)$ showing $f^{-1}(X)\subseteq f^{-1}(Y)$.

Comment: Also, it looks like some people are mentioning that $f^{-1}(y)$ isn't always a single element. This is a subtle part of the definition of a function. However, note that a function is always single valued. In this sense, $f(x)$ is always one element.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that come to mind is that you have to think carefully about using $\in$ and $\subset$. Unless your function is bijective it is a very real possibility that $f^{-1}(y)$ is not an element, but a set. In this event the statement $f^{-1}(y) \in Y$ is not true.

Comment: I had this doubt when I was writing. Should I always assume that $f^{-1}(y)$ is a set?

Comment: $f^{-1}$ can mean an invertible function or the preimage of a set under $f$. I would write $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ for clarity.

Comment: In this case is the inverse image (preimage)

Comment: Yes, this is by definition. To be more precise even in the case of a bijection $f^{-1}(y)$ is a set but it has a single element. Usually we identify the set with the element in this case.

Answer (score 1):

These are the standard definitions:

Let $X, Y$ be any sets whatsover.

$$ f^{-1}(X) = \{ e \in E \ \mid \ f(e) \in X \}$$
$$ f^{-1}(Y) = \{ e \in E \ \mid \ f(e) \in Y \}$$

Your requirement is to prove that the former is a subset of the latter, given $X \subseteq Y$. So we prove the implication

$$ a \in  f^{-1}(X) \implies a \in f^{-1}(Y)   $$

So to this end suppose $a \in  f^{-1}(X)$. The qualification for this is that $ a \in E $ and $ f(a) \in X $. But since, $X \subseteq Y$ any element in $X$ is also an element of $Y$. Hence $ f(a) \in Y$.

So we can extract $ a \in E $ and $f(a) \in Y$ which puts $a \in f^{-1}(Y)$

$\mathscr{Q.E.D.}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
x\in f^{-1}(X) & \implies f(x)\in X\\
& \implies f(x)\in Y\\
& \implies x\in f^{-1}(Y)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

A={x in E : f(x) is in X} = f inverse of a set X

B={x in E : f(x) is in Y} = f inverse of a set Y

if X is subset of Y:
f(x) in X means f(x) in Y 
then A is subset of B